# Processing 3.06b merging programs

Tags: java, processing

i have been working on some code and merging two programs I have created but I understand I am missing a lot of information as I have many errors but I can't seem to fix the error. Below I have included the whole code which has been separated into classes. I am producing a version of space invaders.

Main class:

```
Bullets [] bullets = new Bullets[10];
Player player  = new Player();
Boolean keyLftPressed = false, keyRghtPressed = false;
//Enemies[] enemies = new Enemies();

int state;
String gameLevel = "Main menu";
Boolean startTime = false;
void setup() {
  for(int i=0; i<bullets.length; i++)
  {
    //  if(i%2==0)
    //      bullets[i] = new Bullets();
    //  else
    //      bullets[i] = new Bullets(i);
  }
  size(800, 600);
  state = 0;
  }
void draw() {
  background(255);
  gameState();  
  player1.display();
  movePlayer1();
  handleEnemies();
  handleBullets();
  gamewon();
  }
void gameState() {
  if (gameLevel == "Main menu") {
    background(0);
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    rect(270, 270, 280, 50, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    //Draws rectangle for play game
    fill(0);
    textSize(30);
    text("Play Game", 330, 305);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textSize(50);
    text("Space Invaders", 220, 120);
    if (mousePressed && mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 250 + 280 && mouseY > 270 && mouseY < 270 + 50) 
    {
      gameLevel = "Level 1";
    }
  } else if (gameLevel == "Level 1")
    {
      background (255, 2555 , 255);


    }
}


Bullets Class:

class Bullets {
  class Bullet {
  float x, y;
  float velocity;

  Bullet(float x, float y, float velocity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = velocity;
  }

  void display(){
    fill(80);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 5,15);
  }

  void move(){
    this.y+=this.velocity;
    if (this.y > height || this.y < 0){
      bullets.remove(this);
    }
  }


Class Enemies:

class Enemies {

 float x, y;
  float velocity;
  Enemy(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = 3;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(0,255,0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
    noFill();
  }

  void move() {
    this.x+=this.velocity;
    if (this.x > width*.9) {
      this.x = width*.9;
      this.velocity *= -1;
      this.y+=30;
    }

    if (this.x < width*.1) {
      this.velocity*=-1;
      this.x = width*.1;
      this.y+=30;
    }
  }  

  void hitCheck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
    Bullet b = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);      
    float distBetween = dist(b.x, b.y, this.x, this.y);
    if (distBetween < 15 && b.velocity < 0){
      score++;
    enemies.remove(this);
    float x = width*.1 + i%numCol*50;
    float y = 60 + int(i/numCol)*60 ;
    enemies.add(new Enemy(x, y));

      }
    }
  }  

}


Class Player: 

class Player {

  void movePlayer1() {
  if (keyLftPressed) {
    player1.x -=10;
  }
  if (keyRghtPressed) {
    player1.x +=10;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    keyLftPressed = true;
  }
  else {
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      keyRghtPressed = true;
    }
    else {
      if (key == 'f') {
        player1.shoot();
       }
      }
     }
    }

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    keyLftPressed = false;
  }
  else {
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      keyRghtPressed = false;
    }
  }
}


Class Score:

void gameFinish() {
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {      
    fill(color(255,0,0));
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("Game over", width/2, height/2 - 50);
    text(" Final score : "+ score, width/2, height/2 + 50);
           }
    }
  }
}

 void gamewon()
    {
      if (score == 10)
      {
    background(0);
    fill(color(255,0,0));
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("Congratulations you won!", width/2, height/5);
    text(" Your final score is : "+ score, width/2, height/5 + 30);
    text("Do you wish to continue?",width/2, height/2);  
    text(" If so press Y to Continue or N to exit ", width/2, height/2+30);
    noLoop();
      }
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I basically created 2 progammes and am trying to merge them but am struggling alot to do that now. above i have included the code and classes but have missed out alot of things such as defining the classes or included them in the main sketch and need help with making this program work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to be disheartening, but this code is a mess. You've got a ton of errors here, and asking us to go through all of them is asking quite a bit.

That being said, I'll try to get you started in the right direction.

First of all, you're missing closing curly brackets on several of these classes. Proper indenting will help you narrow this down, or you could consider putting each class in its own tab.

Then in your `Player` class, you use a variable named `player1`. Where is that variable defined? Do you mean to use the `player` variable? For that matter, since you're in the `Player` class already, why are you referring to a variable at all? Shouldn't you just use the `x` variables in that instance directly?

Which brings us to the next problem: your `Player` class doesn't actually define an `x` variable!

Similarly, your `Player` class calls a `shoot()` function, which doesn't seem to exist. You have to define that function.

Then let's see here... your `Score` class uses a `score` variable that doesn't seem to be declared anywhere.

Also, your `bullets` variable is an array, but you're calling functions on it that only work on an `ArrayList` object. Pick one or the other.

You also call a bunch of functions that don't exist: `movePlayer1()`, `handleEnemies()`, `handleBullets()`, and `gameWon()` for example. Some of these functions are defined inside of classes, so you need to use an instance of that class to get to the functions. Like this:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.function();

class Example{
   void function(){
      println("here");
   }
}
```

Then your `Enemies` class has a constructor of `Enemy`, which isn't valid. Choose one or the other.

You're not going to like hearing this, but honestly, your best bet is probably to start from scratch. I would guess that you're trying to copy-paste all of this code from different sources without really understanding what the code is doing, which is a horrible idea. That never works, even for experienced programmers.

Instead, try breaking your problem down into smaller pieces. Get a single rectangle on the screen, then make it move around when you press the arrow keys, then add the ability to shoot. Then try adding some enemies, but only after the previous steps work perfectly!

If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the small step you're stuck on- not your entire project!

Comment: Thanks for the advice and to be totally honest you are correct when you say what I have done is take some code from various other peices and tried to add them all up together but I did this as in one project I created a start and menu screen and created seperate classes whereas in another I created the game without a start screen or classes so I am now trying to combine them. If you want I can upload both codes because I myself now have no idea how to combine both. Thanks for the advice by the way.